# How to set the forms authentication in asp .net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

When I copy my URL and paste in other browser, the page opens which should not happen. This shows lack of security. I want the forms authentication. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you set `cookieless="true"` (or `UseDeviceProfile` and browser has cookies disabled) in your `web.config` file, [authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx) information is appended to the URL and this url will be valid across other browsers. If you use cookies to identify users, then only the current browser will have the user authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this up in your `web.config` file:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" />
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

As described in [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) article.

Answer (score 0):

Forms Authentication is not a newly added concept in asp.net 3.5. It is tried and tested technique in existence from asp.net 1.0. There are lot of books and tutorials available to show you how to do this. The simplest way you can achieve this is using membership provider models such as SqlMembershipProvider. Models provide you ready-made infrastructure which you can use for authentication.